# RuntimeError CUDA initialization Failed only in Python

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I am doing training by using nohup:

```
nohup python -u main.py &> output.txt &
```

I have converted my ipynb to python by using:

```
jupyter nbconvert --to script 'my-notebook.ipynb'
```

When I run the code in jupyter, it works just fine. When I try to run the python script I get `RuntimeError CUDA initialization failed`
I am assigning PCI_BUS_ID for both jupyter and python:

```
try:
    %env CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER=PCI_BUS_ID
    %env CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=5
except NameError:
    os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"] = "PCI_BUS_ID"
    os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "5"
```

I have done 2 successful training. I changed the model a bit and now it is not working.
Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I have fixed it. Since my .ipynb already initialized GPU, python script cannot allocate a  space. I basically shut down the ipynb and and restart the process, .py file is working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the PC always fixes this error for me